# Django Add Multiple Files To Single Instance

Tags: python, django, file, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqi13.jpg)

MY Problem is when i click on extension ID it should display all the audio files relegated to that ID is there any way to upload multiples files Audio Files For Single Instance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iJEy.jpg)

Here Is The Second Image It Showing Only One Audio File But I want to upload multiple audio files

trying to  create different form applying different method in model

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.